# Storefront of Salesforce Commerce Cloud

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

Is Storefront (Salesforce Commerce Cloud) made out of Visualforce page? Or we can use Web Technologies (Node, Angular, Bootstrap etc) to build the Storefront?

Thanks

Comment: As per Salesforce documentation:
"Storefront Reference Architecture leverages JavaScript controllers, Bootstrap 4 development framework, and a model-view-controller architecture approach, making it easy to maintain and update the storefront following initial implementation."
https://www.salesforce.com/products/commerce-cloud/resources/commerce-cloud-storefront-reference-architecture/

Answer (score 4):

Related to Salesforce B2C Commerce (pka Demandware):

Nodejs is server-side technology, which at the moment is not compatible with Salesforce B2C Commerce. Instead the server-side code runs on Rhino engine as per https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/ScriptProgramming/DemandwareJavaScript.html

You can use Angular, Bootstrap, etc. client-side frameworks.

Salesforce B2C Commerce is on different technology stack from the rest of the Salesforce core platform products, so visualforce is not applicable technology.

---

As for Salesforce B2B Commerce (pka CloudCraze):
It is build on top of the core platform so it uses the same technology stack, so visualforce may be applicable depending on your usage scenario.

Check if https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/academy/classes/b2b201-b2b-commerce-technical-training/ course may be helpful for you.